# Object glitched look in viewport, black in camera view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, 3d-view, interface, camera

I'm following along with CrossMind Studio's Blender Day 1 tutorial and my viewport began displaying the following image:

[image: Viewport Glitch]

As shown, in camera view there's a black bar clipping through the scene, and in material preview (and all other modes outside camera view) there are glitchy lines, triangles, and a lot of grey.

When panning the view with Shift + Middle Mouse, the view moves slightly then freezes. Rotating the view with Middle Mouse works, as does Ctrl + Middle Mouse to zoom.

I tried adjusting the clip start and end, but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hello, did you update your graphic card's drivers ? Does your computer respect the minimum specs for using Blender ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, my drivers are up to date. I believe I meet the recommended specs. Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor. Graphics Card: Nvidia GeForce GT 1030. Ram: 16gb